# Android findViewById() problem

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Problem calling TextView from second layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718883/android-problem-calling-textview-from-second-layout-file)

Hey guys the main layout xml file for my activity is R.layout.date_list_layout as it is used as follows

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_list_layout);
```

However I wish to set the text in a TextView from this same activity in another layout xml file R.layout.display_item

I know I would usually use the code below but this is not working as the R.id.currency TextView is not in the main R.layout.date_list_layout....

```
TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currency);
currency.setText(cur);
```

I know the next  line of code is incorrect but is there a way to write a similar line of code to access the R.id.currency in the R.layout.display_item xml or can this not be done?

```
TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.display_item/R.id.currency);
    currency.setText(cur);
```

Some help would really be appreciated as this has me boggled the last two days and I can't find any solution online

Thanks
A

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Android so I am not sure, but I think this should work:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)View.inflate(this, R.layout.display_item, null);
```

"this" would be your Activity.