# Android Problem calling TextView from second layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Hey guys the main layout xml file for my activity is R.layout.date_list_layout as it is used as follows

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.date_list_layout);
```

However I wish to set the text in a TextView from this same activity in another layout xml file R.layout.display_item

I know I would usually use the code below but this is not working as the R.id.currency TextView is not in the main R.layout.date_list_layout....

```
TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currency);
currency.setText(cur);
```

I know the next line of code is incorrect but is there a way to write a similar line of code to access the R.id.currency in the R.layout.display_item xml or can this not be done?

```
TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.display_item/R.id.currency);
currency.setText(cur);
```

Some help would really be appreciated as this has me boggled the last two days and I can't find any solution online

Comment: It would be good if you showed us the xml files that are troubling you.

Comment: @Aaron :please accept answer as your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You first need ot inflate the other xml layout file in order to be able to do stuff on the TextView.

```
(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate(R.layout.display_item);
```

Comment: The second layout file is embeded in the first so would this mean I do not want to inflate it? THe second is only a list item xml file for a ListView in the parent xml file. I tried your line of code but I'm getting an errorfor the context part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should not be done unless you are embedding the layout in the current layout (layout 1) and in that case you need to use include layout.

In case you want to access data and set it from one activity to another. Use SharedPreference to store the text in this activity and when the other activity launches which used the second layout as its content view, you can use this SP to access the data and set the text view.

Comment: I am actually embedding the second layout in the first. It is a group of details for a list item belonging to a ListView found in the parent layout file. So does that mean I need to import the R.layout.display_item xml file? How would I do that? I tried.... import R.layout.display_item but that didn't work

Comment: in your first layout just use this in appropriate place of current layout <include layout="@layout/newlayouttoimport" />

Comment: This seems to be what I need however how do I set the text within the activity. Tried to use a layout Inflater as follows but no luck LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.cur, null);
        
        TextView currency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currency);
        currency.setText("test");

Comment: You do not need to use Layout Inflater. Once you include the layout in your current layout all the ids are automatically available you need to simply call ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.currency)).setText("test");

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve yuor problems with Intent data.
You're starting your activity via Intent, right?
If so, just pass desired data (cur...) via Intent and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As Second TextView is the part of another layout so we have to used

```
 setContentView(R.layout.R.layout.display_item);
```

So for second TextView Change you code to

```
setContentView(R.layout.display_item);

TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.display_item/R.id.currency);

currency.setText(cur);
```